# delegate modal view swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have tried the other methods for delegation and protocols for passing data between modal views and the parent view button they aren't working for me. This is obviously because I am implementing them wrong.

What I have is a parent view controller which has a tableviewcell which in the right detail will tell you your selection from the modal view. The modal view is another table view which allows you to select a cell, which updates the right detail and dismisses the modal view. All is working except the actual data transfer.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Here is my code for the parent view controller:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

//Properties

var delegate: transferData?

//Outlets
@IBOutlet var productLabel: UILabel! 
@IBOutlet var rightDetail: UILabel!





override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println(delegate?.productCarrier)
    println(delegate?.priceCarrier)
    if delegate?.productCarrier != "" {
        rightDetail.text = delegate?.productCarrier
        productLabel.text = delegate?.productCarrier
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 5
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}



}
```

The code for the model view controller and protocol is:

```
protocol transferData {
var priceCarrier: Double { get set }
var productCarrier: String { get set }
}

class ProductsDetailsViewController: UITableViewController, transferData {
//Properties

var priceCarrier = 00.00
var productCarrier = ""


//Outlets


//Actions

@IBAction func unwindToViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    populateDefaultCategories()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return Int(Category.allObjects().count)
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return (Category.allObjects()[UInt(section)] as Category).name
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return Int(objectsForSection(section).count)


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:ProductListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("productCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ProductListCell

    let queriedProductResult = objectForProductFromSection(indexPath.section, indexPath.row)

    cell.name.text = queriedProductResult.name
    cell.prices.text = "$\(queriedProductResult.price)"

return cell


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!

    let product = objectForProductFromSection(indexPath.section, indexPath.row)

    let PVC: TableViewController = TableViewController()

    println("didSelect")
    productCarrier = product.name
    priceCarrier = product.price

    println(productCarrier)
    println(priceCarrier)


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for passing data, you should use segue like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
let product = objectForProductFromSection(indexPath.section, indexPath.row)

println("didSelect")
productCarrier = product.name
priceCarrier = product.price

println(productCarrier)
println(priceCarrier)

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("displayYourTableViewControllerSegue", sender: self)
```

}

and then  override the `prepareForSegue` function:

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var controller = segue.destinationViewController as TableViewController
    controller.rightDetail.text = "\(self.priceCarrier)"
    controller.productLabel.text = self.productCarrier
  }
```

Comment: So which code goes in which file sorry? Thanks though @Florian

Comment: Sorry I implemented this and it is still not working. Is there a way to do it with delegates? @thelion

Comment: All this code goes to the Container file. What didn't work? Because using delegate to transfer data feel weird. For me, delegate should be used for call back functions (for exemple).
Furthermore, you will have to create a protocol each time you will need to transfer data.